# Basic git bash alias config

Tags: git

I'm very new to Git and having trouble setting a basic alias.

When I set the alias in .gitconfig file

```
[alias]
    tech="cd c:/wamp/www/technology/"
```

and then try to call `git tech`

I get the following error

```
Expansion of alias 'tech' failed; 'cd' is not a git command
```

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: git aliases can make shortcuts to git commands, not arbitrary shell commands.

Comment: Okay, thats good to know. How would I go about making a shortcut to whatever directory that i'm working in?

Comment: @Mitch Glenn: describe your original task? What you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to open my Git Bash and instead of typing `cd c:/wamp/www/technology`, i'd like to just be able to type `git tech` and have it take me to that directory. This is my first time using Git and i'm not familiar with command prompts, but i'm trying to learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like more of a shell alias rather than a git alias.

You'd want to set this up in your `~/.bashrc` (or similar, depending on your shell).  But, in bash, it would be:

`alias tech="cd c:/wamp/www/technology"`

Comment: in bash it wouldn't be `c:/...` at first place :-)

Comment: Thanks, I added the alias line to my .bash_profile and now its working.

Comment: @zerkms - maybe Cygwin?